Typescript issues when using sequelize's Op.between
I am sure I am doing something wrong but I just can't figure out what exactly, I'd appreciate any hint please.
In my service function I have the following which fails (Visual Studio Code underlines the where clause):
const getExtractionModels = async (repoId: number, filterFrom: Date, filterTo: Date): Promise<ExtractionModel[]> => {
    return await ExtractionModel.findAll({
        where: { 
            // repositoryRef: repoId,
            startDate: {
                [Op.between]: [filterFrom, filterTo]
            }
        }
    })
}

In some stackoverflow forum entry I found that string (.toISOString()) should be passed to Op.between but it didn't help.
The model class is
@Table({ tableName: 'extraction' })
export class ExtractionModel extends Model<InferAttributes<ExtractionModel>, InferCreationAttributes<ExtractionModel>> {

    ...

    @Attribute(DataTypes.DATE)
    @Default(DataTypes.NOW)
    declare startDate: CreationOptional<Date>

    @Attribute(DataTypes.STRING)
    @NotNull
    declare branches: string

    ...
}

The error message that Typescript produces is
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(this: ModelStatic<ExtractionModel>, options: Omit<FindOptions<InferAttributes<ExtractionModel, { omit: never; }>>, "raw"> & { raw: true; }): Promise<...>', gave the following error.
    Type '{ startDate: { [OpTypes.between]: Date[]; }; }' is not assignable to type 'WhereOptions<InferAttributes<ExtractionModel, { omit: never; }>>'.
      Types of property 'startDate' are incompatible.
    Type '{ [OpTypes.between]: Date[]; }' is not assignable to type 'WhereAttributeHashValue<Date & { [CreationAttributeBrand]?: true | undefined; }>'.
      Types of property '[Op.between]' are incompatible.
        Type 'Date[]' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(this: ModelStatic<ExtractionModel>, options?: FindOptions<InferAttributes<ExtractionModel, { omit: never; }>> | undefined): Promise<...>', gave the following error.
    Type '{ startDate: { [OpTypes.between]: Date[]; }; }' is not assignable to type 'WhereOptions<InferAttributes<ExtractionModel, { omit: never; }>>'.
      Types of property 'startDate' are incompatible.
    Type '{ [OpTypes.between]: Date[]; }' is not assignable to type 'WhereAttributeHashValue<Date & { [CreationAttributeBrand]?: true | undefined; }>'.
      Types of property '[Op.between]' are incompatible.
        Type 'Date[]' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.ts(2769)
model.d.ts(96, 3): The expected type comes from property 'where' which is declared here on type 'Omit<FindOptions<InferAttributes<ExtractionModel, { omit: never; }>>, "raw"> & { raw: true; }'

I also tried another column but the error is the same, for example:
    return await ExtractionModel.findAll({
        where: { 
            // repositoryRef: repoId,
            branches: {
                [Op.eq]: '1'
            }
        }
    })

Any hint please why the Op operations don't work?
Is it related that I use decorators in the model...? (I hope it isn't)
"@sequelize/core": "^7.0.0-alpha.37",
"sequelize": "^6.37.3",

Thanks!
+++++++++++++++++ UPDATE +++++++++++++++++
The error is when using [Op.between]: [filterFrom, filterTo]:
Type '{ repositoryRef: number; status: string; startDate: { [OpTypes.between]: Date[]; }; }' is not assignable to type 'WhereOptions<InferAttributes<ExtractionModel, { omit: never; }>>'.
  Types of property 'startDate' are incompatible.
    Type '{ [OpTypes.between]: Date[]; }' is not assignable to type 'WhereAttributeHashValue<Date & { [CreationAttributeBrand]?: true | undefined; }>'.
      Types of property '[Op.between]' are incompatible.

and in case of [Op.eq]: '1'
Type '{ branches: { [OpTypes.eq]: string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'WhereOptions<InferAttributes<ExtractionModel, { omit: never; }>>'.
  Types of property 'branches' are incompatible.
    Type '{ [OpTypes.eq]: string; }' is not assignable to type 'WhereAttributeHashValue<string>'.
      Types of property '[Op.eq]' are incompatible.

Currently I can execute only equality operator in database with sequelize. I hope this error is nothing to do with decorators used in my model class. They should work with Op, shouldn't they?

Could you match the error and the code example (even if errors are similar)?

I tried the case with branches and Op.eq and linter has no complaints about it. How did you import 'Op'?

My "solution" was to use sequelize-typescript and everything was hunky-dory afterwards.
